# Compare the color of two QColor objects

Tags: c++, qt, qcolor

I'm implementing tests for my Qt application using an 'internal test library'. The problem is that the library does not provide an option to compare two `QColor` objects.

Is that correct to use the following code to compare the color of two **QColor** objects?

```
void MyClass::compare(QColor color1, QColor color2)
{
    ASSERT_EQ(color1.red(), color2.red());
    ASSERT_EQ(color1.green(), color2.green());
    ASSERT_EQ(color1.blue(), color2.blue());
    ASSERT_EQ(color1.alpha(), color2.alpha());
}
```

Or rather, is it enough to compare the red, green, blue and alpha channels to consider the two colors equal?

**Note**: in this case, I need to know exactly what channel 'does not match', so I can't just use the `==` operator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`QColor` has `operator ==`. Just try `if(color1 == color2)`...

Documentation here.  (As you can see it compares RGB and alpha.)

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qcolor.html#operator-eq-eq

Comment: Hope you don't mind me adding a link to your answer Ashwel?

Comment: Yes, `operator==()` should always be the first thing we try, and only worry about implementing the comparison ourselves if the class author didn't already.

Comment: Sorry, I was not much clear on my question I have updated it.

Comment: As you mentioned, the documentation says it compares the RGB and alpha colors, so it seems my compare function works as expected (Documentation: Returns true if this color has the same RGB and alpha values as color; otherwise returns false).